# How to do a query to compare this year vs last year sales?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm relatively new to SQL and trying to make a simple query to look at this years sales on a day vs last year same date or ideally same day of the week.

I have created the following query which currently based on a single set day. I will need to move this to get todays date really but thought id tackle that one later.

-

```
Below is the query
-strtrdecode = store location
-dtmtradedate = transaction date
-cursales = sales value
-Target = will contain Targets but i haven't generated any yet but need to show -the field
```

Would someone please show me how to show both this year and last year figures please on the same line for each store

i.e

```
liverpool, 01/06/2015, 4000,3000
blackpool, 01/06/2015, 6000, 7500 etc..
```

Thank you in advance

Mike

```
TABLE_CATALOG   TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME
> DRSData   dbo DAILYSALES  STRSALETYPE 
> DRSData   dbo DAILYSALES  STRTRADECODE
> DRSData   dbo DAILYSALES  CURSALES
> DRSData   dbo DAILYSALES  DTMTRADEDATE
> DRSData   dbo DAILYSALES  INTTRANSNUM



 *SELECT        strtradecode, dtmtradedate, sum(cursales) as [Actual SALES TY], '' as Target
    FROM            DAILYSALES 
                             where (STRSALETYPE = 'H' )and (DTMTRADEDATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-06-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-06-01 00:00:00', 
                             102))
                             group by strtradecode, dtmtradedate*
```

Comment: Show us your table schema and please tag with the appropriate version of SQL you are using.

Comment: Really stupid question it would seem, where do i find the table schema?

Comment: No stupid questions, only stupid answers :-) ... Just show us the table names and columns, that's all.

Comment: table name: DAILYSALES  , columns: STRSALETYPE
STRTRADECODE
CURSALES
DTMTRADEDATE
INTTRANSNUM

Comment: I have added this to the above question

Answer (score 0):

**Okay, bear with me as this is my first attempt at an answer and I'm also very new to SQL.**

I'm attempting to learn, but I want to get more involved here. I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way to perform what you want to do but like I said I'm very new and this is the only way I know how. I'm completely open to corrections and help. Thanks!

```
-- 1. Began by declaring the dates. 
-- 2. Then created a temp table.
-- 3. Inserted into the temp table
-- 4. Created JOINS to separate the dates you wanted. 
-- 5. SELECTED fields from the temp table for the desired output.

-- Step 1

DECLARE  @startDate1   DATETIME2 = '01/01/2014', -- Creating previous year
         @endDate1     DATETIME2 = '12/31/2014', -- Creating previous year
         @startDate2   DATETIME2 = '01/01/2015', -- Creating this year
         @endDate2     DATETIME2 = '12/31/2015'; -- Creating this year
-- Step 2

DECLARE @yearFigures TABLE (    -- Created temp table with your desired output
       StoreLocation VARCHAR(20),
       TransactionDt VARCHAR(10),
       PreviousYear VARCHAR(20),
       CurrentYear VARCHAR(20))

-- Step 3

INSERT INTO @yearFigures        -- Inserting into your temp table
SELECT DISTINCT
       strtrdecode,
       CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), dtmtradedate, 101),
       sales1.cs1,
       sales2.cs2
FROM DAILYSALES dls

-- Step 4

LEFT OUTER JOIN(
    SELECT cursales AS cs1
    FROM DAILYSALES dls
    WHERE dtmtradedate BETWEEN @startDate1 AND @endDate1
    GROUP BY cursales ) AS sales1 ON sales1.cursales = dls.cursales -- Year one
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT cursales AS cs2
    FROM DAILYSALES dls
    WHERE dtmtradedate BETWEEN @startDate2 AND @endDate2
    GROUP BY cursales ) AS sales2 ON sales2.cursales = dls.cursales; -- Year two

-- Step 5

SELECT StoreLocation,
       TransactionDt,
       SalesValue,
       SalesValue2
FROM @yearFigures -- From here you're pulling from your temp table (your output)
```

You should get what you're looking for with this. The LEFT OUTER JOIN's separated sales values years and named them. I ran it on one of my dbo's for 1 row and got this

```
StoreLocation  TransactionDt  PreviousYear   CurrentYear
AESKAGGS         03/14/2014     828.35         400.00
```

AGAIN go easy on me guys.. I'm a noob.